# how to print String in the queue basic loop

Tags: java

I want to create a method that runs all of jobs in a queue(a Job list). I have created a method to run one job(`runAJob`), and below method is to run all of jobs in the queue list, until the time(myTimeLeft)runs out.
now, this code always leaves 1 ArraLyist when I run  `runAll` method. Would anyone tell me why it is wrong?

```
   /**
  * Run the first job on the queue if there is enough time on the clock and the job queue list is not empty.
  * And move the job to the finished jobs list.
  */
public void runAJob(){
   myJobDuration = myJobInQueue.get(0).getDuration();
   if(!myJobInQueue.isEmpty())
   {
        if (myJobDuration < myTimeLeft)
        {
            myTimeLeft = myTimeLeft - myJobDuration;
            myFinishedJobs.add(myJobInQueue.get(0));
            System.out.println("A job is running: " + myJobInQueue.get(0).getName());
            myJobInQueue.remove(0);
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Not enogth running time left, please add time on the clock.");             
        }
   }
   else 
   {
     System.out.println("No pending job on the list.");
   }
}

/**
  * Run all the jobs on the queue in order until it runs out of time.
  */  
public void runAll()
{
  int counAJob =0; 
  while (myJobDuration < myTimeLeft && !myJobInQueue.isEmpty()) {
   // get next item from queue
     runAJob();
     System.out.println("A job is running: ");
  }

}
```

Comment: `this code always leaves 1 ArraLyist` -> Where is ArrayList? Can you post some more code? Your `runAJob()` method and where is your `myTimeLeft` defined?

Comment: Also where are you changing myTimeLeft?

Comment: @LewsTherin. Probably in `runAJob()` method.

Comment: `myTimeLeft` and `myJobDuration` could possibly be the problem, how are they defined? When are they changed ?

Comment: I have re-posted my question. this time I have included runAJob method. And this still does not work. can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a for-loop when you're (presumably) using a Queue? You don't make any decisions based on the size of the queue (`i`). I would just stick to letting the Queue handle itself:

```
// declarations and definitions

while (myJobDuration < myTimeLeft && !myJobInQueue.isEmpty()) {
    // get next item from queue
    runAJob();
}
```